# Reload Page In Ui.Router Gives 404 Error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, http-status-code-404

I am developing an angular app with ui.router. When reloading the index page it shows 404 error.My code in app.js

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){


            $stateProvider
            .state('/',{
                            url:'/login',
                            data:{
                                    body_class:'nav-md',
                                    side_bar:true
                            },
                            views:{
                                    'main':{
                                            templateUrl:'opshub_rout/partials/login.html'
                                    }
                            }

            })
            .state('dash',{
                            url:'/dashboard',
                            data:{
                                    body_class:'nav-md',
                                    side_bar:true
                            },
                            views:{
                                    'main':{
                                            templateUrl:'partials/dashboard.html'
                                }
                        }
            })
            .state('base_pay',{
                            url:'/base_pay',
                            data:{
                                    body_class:'nav-md',
                                    side_bar:true
                            },
                            views:{
                                    'main':{
                                            templateUrl:'partials/add_base_pay.html'
                                }
                        }
            });             

        }]);

        app.run(['$state','$rootScope', function($state, $rootScope){

            $state.go('/', {}, {reload:true});



        }]);
```

First time loading in url: localhost/myapp/#
But When reloading Url: localhost/index.html

Server side doing in another location, so is there any solution to solve this issue from client side? Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use HTML5 mode for URLs ?

Comment: No,How can I use that?